# How find sum of negative values in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I am using inline assembly in c++. However, my code does not work properly, It always returns 0. I want to find some of negative values and show.
Could you please help me out?

PS: I have used debugging but could not find the problem

```
void func(const int* arr, size_t arr_rows, size_t arr_cols, int* result)
{
    int sum = 0;
    _asm
    {
        mov ebx, [arr] ///address
        mov edx, 0; //sum
        mov ecx, [arr_rows] // number of rows

        row_loop:
        push ecx // save number of rows
            xor esi, esi // reset column offset for the current row
            mov ecx, [arr_cols]  //  number of column
    col_loop :

            add ebx, esi;
            cmp ebx, 0
            jge bigger_case

            jl less_case
            jmp n_case

    less_case :
            add esi, 4
            add edx, dword ptr[ebx + esi];
            loop col_loop
            
    bigger_case:
            add esi, 4
            loop col_loop

      n_case: 
            add esi, 4
                add ebx, esi // move to the next row offset
                pop ecx // restore row loop counter
                loop row_loop;
            
    ending:
        mov sum, edx;
    }
    cout << sum<<" is answer"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to access the element for the comparison. Also, the `less_case` is accessing the next element not the current one because you have the `add esi, 4` in the wrong place. Also also your `loop col_loop` fall through. Furthermore the `jmp n_case` is pointless because one of the two previous conditionals of course already jumped away.

Comment: could you write proper way please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Review

> ```
>   cmp ebx, 0
> ```

This compares an address to 0. You need to compare a value from the array.

> ```
>   add esi, 4
>   add edx, dword ptr[ebx + esi];
> ```

This adds the **next** element to the sum. You need the **current** element.

> ```
>   loop col_loop
>                 <=== This is a 'fall through'
> bigger_case:
>   add esi, 4
>   loop col_loop
> ```

If the row's last element would happen to be negative, then this fall through in the code would start a very long loop!

> ```
>   jge bigger_case
>   jl less_case
>   jmp n_case
> less_case :
> ```

Once you know it's not greater nor equal, then it's got to be less. Here you can indeed rightfully fall through in the *less_case*.

You can easily address the array elements without using the extra `ESI` offset. Just always `add ebx, 4`, much cleaner.

### Solution

You don't need to solve this task with nested loops. Just calculate the total number of elements and use a single loop.

```
  xor  edx, edx
  mov  esi, [arr]
  mov  ecx, [arr_rows]
  imul ecx, [arr_cols]
more:
  mov  eax, [esi]
  test eax, eax         ; TEST is efficient to inspect the sign
  jns  skip
  add  edx, eax         ; Only adding negative values
skip:            
  add  esi, 4
  dec  ecx
  jnz  more
```

Better not use the `LOOP` instruction. See [Why is the loop instruction slow? Couldn't Intel have implemented it efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently)